# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-select/async'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I've installed react-select 3.1.0
but when i try to import this file as defined in documentation it's giving me error.

**TypeScript error in /home/.../src/core/components/kiosk/Component_file.tsx(3,25):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-select/async'. '/home/.../node_modules/react-select/async/dist/react-select.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7016**

import code line:

```
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
```

Thank you advance for solving my problem

Comment: Did you install @types/react-select?

Comment: everything is installed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i was working in typescript. I just changed package path. I prefix it with @types.

```
@types/react-select/async
```

You can see @types directory in node_modules.

Comment: Do you mean you used `import AsyncSelect from '@types/react-select/async';`? Because that does not work